# Java- Processing Json array based on keys

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm getting this string (from webservice) into a JSONArray,

```
[{
    "textinput": [{
        "position": 0,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 0,
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }, {
        "position": 2,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 1,
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }]
}, {
    "textarea": [{
        "position": 1,
        "type": "textarea",
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 0
    }]
}]
```

I need to sort the array by ascending order based on key-"position"
I am using org.json library, the below code is the one so far the code i used

```
JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();
List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
}

Collections.sort( jsonList, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

    public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
        String valA = new String();
        String valB = new String();

        try {
            valA = (String) a.get("position");
            valB = (String) b.get("position");
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            //do something
        }

        return valA.compareTo(valB);
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    sortedJsonArray.put(jsonList.get(i));
}
```

AALso tried other links in the site.
please  help

Comment: Use php to sort a array that is very easy

Comment: What is the error you getting? Do you want to optimise this code?

Comment: @vinoth12594 thanks. but i can't because the sorted array needs to be passed on to an android application

Comment: @NarendraPandey  yes i want to optimize the code the error is array index out of bound exception

Comment: @Vishal Just try Rahul's answer it'll work currently you are comparing String thats why its not working convert that in to Integer

Comment: @NarendraPandey  the error is Number format exception at try catch for getting "position.

Comment: @Nisarg am getting the above error

Comment: getter seems to be incorrect.Why are you using get("Positions") instead of getPosition()??

Answer (score 1):

Try TreeMap, it will automatically sort the array for you. All you have to do is make "position" the Key of TreeMap and JSONObject the value. The treemap will arrange the values in ascending order of the keys.And then you can retrieve the JSONObject values from the treemap.

```
    private TreeMap<Integer,JSONObject> sortedarray = new TreeMap<Integer,JONObject>();


    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            sortedarray.put(Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("position")+""),jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now if you want it to be a jsonArray only..

```
    JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for(int x = 0; x<sortedarray.size();x++)
        {

            //assuming that positions you get in JSON are always complete like 1,2,3,4,....,10,...,100.
              sortedJsonArray.put(sortedarray.get(x));

            //assuming that positions you get in JSON are not always complete like 1,3,4,..,10,13,...,100.( misses a few numbers in between like 2 and 11 in this case)  
            sortedJsonArray.put(sortedarray.get(Integer.parseInt(advanceplay.get(advanceplay.keySet().toArray()[i]))));

        }
```